# Editor Ace with Internet Explorer 8/9 does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, internet-explorer, ace-editor

I'm using the Editor Ace in json mode and have problems with IE8 and 9.
In internet explorer 8 will not work directly in the 9th I do not load the json worker and error that I have is:
"Could not load worker"
The editor starts but no validations are loaded.
I am using the non-conflict version. 
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds
My code is very simple and is as follows:

```
var editor = ace.edit("json-div");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/github");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/json");
```

I tried using the version for ie7 with https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/demo/ie7.html example. But it does not work.

```
ace.require("ace/ext/old_ie");
var editor = ace.edit("xml-div");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/github");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/json");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax checking doesn't work on IE versions < 10 because they do not support webworkers the workaraound is to use [UIWorkerClient](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.8/demo/kitchen-sink/demo.js#L82-L85) see  https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/2091

Not working on ie8/7 is a new regression, please report it to https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues